# Balance Sheet Value of a Repo

Tags: interest-rates, valuation, accounting, banking-regulations, repo

I am relatively new to repos and I am trying to find out whether there is a standard practice for calculating balance sheet value of a repo. Are there any regulations that prescribe how banks shall calculate balance sheet value of a repo? Would the following approach make sense for a fixed rate term repo?
$$V(t) = N\left\{1 + R(t_0)(t – t_0) + \frac{(R(t_0) – R(t))(T – t)} {1 + R(t)(T - t)}\right\}=N\left\{R(t_0)(t – t_0) + \frac{1+R(t_0)(T-t)} {1 + R(t)(T - t)}\right\},$$

where
$N$ - repo notional (amount of cash borrowed),
$t_0$ – repo contract start time,
$t$ – valuation time,
$T$ – repo maturity time,
$R(t)$ – repo rate at time $t$,
$R(t_0)(t – t_0)$ is the accrued interest.

Comment: Are you asking for the balance sheet value (whatever that is) or the market value ? Also: a repo transaction usually involves at least two legs. Where is that in your formula ? This [link](https://viewpoint.pwc.com/dt/us/en/pwc/accounting_guides/transfers_and_servic/transfers_and_servic_US/chapter_5_accounting_US/55_repurchase_agreem_US.html) gives some taste what kind of science in itself the balance sheet treatment of repos can be. I am not an expert of balance sheet treatment of derivatives at all.

Comment: Thank you, Kurt, for the feedback and for the link. I am actually interested in both. In case repos are accounted on a fair market value basis in a given bank, shouldn't balance sheet value of a repo equal to its market value? If I understand it correctly,  collateral leg of a repo doesn't directly impact its market value. My understanding is that collateral affects it only indirectly via a choice of the discounting rate that should depend on collateral quality. For example, repo cash flow with a low quality collateral shall have a greater discounting rate.